# The installer encountered an unrecoverable error and will now reboot

Tags: installation

or "and will now run a desktop...."

I tried installing it with a CD..
it installs ubuntu to a certain point and then stops (after the name password window).. the last thing I see before the error pops up is a big white window with an ">" on the right side.

I tried to gather some debug info via ctrl+alt+f2 but whenever I type something in it tells me I do not have permission to do so.

Comment: This is not a corrupt media problem - I verified two different burns. It seems to be the slideshow package. The slideshow program comes up on the screen just before the error...

Answer (score 7):

Follow these steps to fix the problem:

1. TRY Ubuntu from USB or CD
2. Open terminal, and type:

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove ubiquity-slideshow-ubuntu
   ```
3. Start the installation

Comment: Why will this work? What about the slideshow causes problems?

Comment: this solution worked for me perfectly with 12.10 on a Sony Vaio. Slideshow was crushing the installation process abruptly. I removed `ubiquity-slideshow-ubuntu` from terminal during re-installation (thus the slideshow local url could not be found and accessed) and installation continued and exited normally.

Comment: This solution also worked for me when installing 20.04 inside VirtualBox.  I initially thought this issue was a HyperV issue, but after testing with it turned on/off this solved it.

Comment: another solution is downgrading vm compatibility. For example, downgrade from EXSI 7.0 to workstation 12.

Answer (score 5):

It seems likely that your installation media is corrupted--in my experience, that's the most common cause of this kind of installation error.

You should [MD5 test the `.iso` image](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) you downloaded. If that doesn't check out, then you'll have to download a new `.iso` and start over.

If it does check out, then you should [check the installation media for defects](http://zootlinux.blogspot.com/2010/05/check-disc-for-defects-in-ubuntu-1004.html). This applies to both CD/DVD media and to USB flash drives.