# Ubuntu 14.04 Live USB installer will not run

Tags: usb, system-installation, ubiquity

I'm currently trying to update from 12.04 to 14.04 with a live USB which I made using the Startup Disk Creator application. However, whenever I boot up with it, it takes several minutes to start up, and I receive the following error:

```
Installation failed    

The installer encountered an unrecoverable error.  A desktop session will now be started...
```

I found [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145437/the-installer-encountered-an-unrecoverable-error-and-will-now-reboot) which seemed similar, but I tried everything suggested there with no results. I verified the md5sum of the iso I used to make the USB image, and that checked out. Removing ubiquity slideshow as suggested in one of the answers also did not help, so I re-added that.

Whenever I try to run ubiquity to install Ubuntu 14.04, it just hangs (with the rotating waiting mouse icon) and then eventually closes.

I'm trying to install on a 64-bit HP Envy-15t, which is currently dual-booted with Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 12.04, and I'm using the 64-bit Ubuntu desktop iso.

Does anyone know a fix for this?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that something was corrupted with my .iso even though the md5sums matched.  I redownloaded the image and remade the live USB and it installed fine.

Comment: This is true usually the USB is mostly the first place to check